# Best way to inherit from User table (SQLAlchemy & UserMixin)

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a SQLALchemy table:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(40), nullable=False)
```

But I want users to be able login and register using either by creating a new account with username and password, or using a social media account (google/twitter/vk.com). My idea is to have a base User table that will have abstract methods like get_name() that will have to be defined in the derived tables for each social media.

Pseudocode for this:

Base user

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    # Overridden method from UserMixin
    def get_id(self):
        return self.user_id

    def get_name(self): raise NotImplementedError
```

Google user

```
class GoogleUser(User):

    first_name = db.Columnn(db.String(40), nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Columnn(db.String(40), nullable=False)

    def get_name(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

E-mail user

```
class EmailUser(User):
    username = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(40), nullable=False)

    def get_name(self):
        return self.username
```

The question is what is the best way to implement it with SQLAlchemy & UserMixin?
Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

What I usually do is create a `User` model with all the information that is needed by the application e.g.

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(40), nullable=True)
```

Then for third party services authentication, I create a table which stores token and other relevant data regarding that service that the application requirese.g.

```
class GoogleUser(db.Model):

    first_name = db.Column(db.String(40), nullable=False)
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(40), nullable=False)
    google_token = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
```

I connect this new table to the `User` model via foreign key:

```
google_user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("google_user.id"))
```

This way the user can easily connect their third party accounts and have an account on your application.

Facebook Login's [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/multiple-providers) also recommends this

Hope it clears things up!